# Servant-options does not handle OPTIONS request

Tags: haskell, cors, servant

I am using servant-options packages as described in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-options):

```
type RepositoryAPI = "repository" :> Get '[JSON] Repository 

getRepository :: Handler Repository
getRepository = do
  repository <- liftIO loadRawRepositoryFromFilesystem 
  return repository

server :: Server RepositoryAPI 
server = getRepository 

repositoryAPI :: Proxy RepositoryAPI 
repositoryAPI = Proxy

app :: Application
app = logStdoutDev
  $ cors (const $ Just policy)
  $ provideOptions repositoryAPI 
  $ serve repositoryAPI server
    where policy = simpleCorsResourcePolicy { 
          corsMethods = ["OPTIONS", "GET", "PUT", "POST"],
          corsRequestHeaders = [ "Authorization", "Content-Type" ] 
    }

main :: IO ()
main = run 8081 app
```

But OPTIONS request to the URL still returns error 400:

```
OPTIONS /repository
  Accept: */*
  Status: 400 Bad Request 0.000039136s
```

What am I doing wrong? Tried with different policy configurations (no "Authorization" or no corsMethods or with lower case "content-type"), but still no luck. Could this be something I need to handle on the front-end? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was on front-end. I had to do the following call with `d3.json` method:

```
json("http://localhost:8081/repository", 
    {method: 'GET', headers: new Headers(
         [['Access-Control-Request-Headers', "content-type"]]
    )}
)
```

Previously I was doing the following:

```
json("http://localhost:8081/repository", 
    {method: 'GET', headers: new Headers(
         [['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*"]]
    )}
)
```

So now it all works.